# Selenium Chrome Driver displays page differently then manually navigating to link

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-testing

I have a strange issue using Selenium Web driver with C#.

When I navigate to [this webpage](http://www.sangar.ee/et/mensshirts/meeste-sark-franco-s310166890.html) manually in Chrome or using the Firefox Selenium WebDriver then the following "Proovikabiin" link is displayed.

[image]
[image]

But when using the Chrome WebDriver the button is not displayed.

[image]

What in the world would cause this behavior difference?  I prefer to keep my tests passing browser agnostic.

[Edit] Software Versions

- Selenium.WebDriver, 2.26.0. Installed via NuGet.
- Chrome WebDriver, 23.0.1240.0 from
  [here](http://chromedriver.googlecode.com/files/chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0.zip).  The photo showing the button was created from the same chrome instance launched by the web driver, but just copy and pasting the link.
- I'm using the built-in Firefox driver.  Currently Firefox 17.0.1
  installed on computer.

Here's some code.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace IntegrationMonitorLibrary.WebTests.FailFolder
{
    [TestFixture]
    class BrowserInconsistancyWithProovikabiinButton
    {
        [Test]
        public void FirefoxShowsButton()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            var url = "http://www.sangar.ee/et/mensshirts/meeste-sark-franco-s310166890.html";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

            var buttonId = "fitsmebutton";
            driver.FindElement(By.Id(buttonId)).Click();
        }

        [Test]
        public void ChromeDoesNotShowButton()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            var url = "http://www.sangar.ee/et/mensshirts/meeste-sark-franco-s310166890.html";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

            var buttonId = "fitsmebutton";
            driver.FindElement(By.Id(buttonId)).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Selenium? What version of Chrome? What version of Chrome Driver? What version of Firefox?

Comment: I couldn believe it, so I tried it and you are indeed correct.